# Return full data on JavaScript Promise for a function within a class while using node-client-ntlm

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a function within a class that makes a call and returns a promise object with data. I do get the data back the issue is I cannot figure out how to make the call wait till all of the data is returned at the moment it only returns a few lines of data and cuts off the rest of the return.

```
  async callCurl(postFields) {
    this.postFields = postFields;
    const response = await client
      .request(
        {
          url: this.url,
          method: "POST",
          debug: true,
          body: "folderGuid=" + this.postFields,
          headers: {
            "content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
          },
          resolve: true,
        },
        "username",
        "password",
        "",
        "domain"
      )
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response.body);
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
    
    //return response;
  }
```

Comment: If it's cut off then there's either something wrong with the HTTP Client you are using, or with the server. The code you shared here looks fine.

Comment: @Evert If I make the same call in php using curl or postman I get the full return. Its so strange. Im a JS noob so i cant even tell if im doing something wrong.

Comment: @demo7up why do you use an unpopular library then?

Comment: If it's the server that's broken, there's a possibility that some clients are more resilient against this. Or maybe something is different such as HTTP vs HTTP/2.

Comment: @Konrad because I cant find any other library to handle NTLM authentication properly.

Comment: But it could be a badly implemented client library.

Comment: Try this https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios-ntlm or this https://www.npmjs.com/package/httpntlm

Comment: @Konrad thank you will try it now and report back!

Comment: @Konrad Your are the absolute man, I had a hard time with Axios but httpntlm worked like a charm!!! TYVM please add it as the answer to be accepted!